# Any material for learning Computational Contact Mechanics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, contact-mechanics

I am currently studying computational contact mechanics for my research. Does anyone know some good material (especially introductory material) for this subject? I have already read the following two books roughly and found them too difficult for me.

*Computational Contact Mechanics* by Peter Wriggers.

*Computational Contact and Impact Mechanics* by Tod A. Laursen.

They are both very nice books but not that friendly to me. I think maybe some introductory books or courses are what I need now.

Answer (score 0):

Intro to nonlinear finite element analysis by Nam Ho Kim

Intro to computational contact mechanics by Konyuhov and Izi

Comment: Please read about [How should I answer a resource recommendation question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/4698#4698). You should additional details about those references. Thank you.